# GetFeature EqualTo filter incluiding substring function?

Tags: geoserver, sld, filter

I have the following table as a layer in geoserver:

[image]

I'm trying to get the features with the first 3 characters of the `codigo` field matching the Literal.

When doing a GetFeature request with `EqualTo` filter I get features even if the 3 first `codigo` characters are not equal to the literal. Note that `codigo` is an string. This is my filter:

```
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <Function name="strSubstring">
            <PropertyName>codigo</PropertyName>
            <Literal>0</Literal>
            <Literal>3</Literal>
        </Function>
        <Literal>201</Literal>
    </PropertyIsEqualTo>
</Filter>
```

Is there something wrong with the filter?

Comment: TBH I'd expect it to return no features at all as I wouldn't expect strSubstring to work on numeric attributes.

Comment: @IanTurton `codigo` is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I make the following request to a local GeoServer it works as expected, returning New York, New Hampshire and New Mexico:

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs                       http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states">                                            
    <ogc:Filter>                                                                
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>                                                   
        <ogc:Function name="strSubstring">                                      
          <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>                       
          <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>                                          
          <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>                                          
        </ogc:Function>                                                         
        <ogc:Literal>New</ogc:Literal>                                          
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>                                                  
    </ogc:Filter>                                                               
  </wfs:Query>                                                                  
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And even if you try it on a numeric column (MANUAL) it works fine, this returns Washington:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>                                                       
    <ogc:Function name="strSubstring">                                          
      <ogc:PropertyName>MANUAL</ogc:PropertyName>                               
      <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>                                              
      <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>                                              
    </ogc:Function>                                                             
    <ogc:Literal>302</ogc:Literal>                                              
  </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>                                                      
</ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I didn't apply correctly the `And` Filter (I have one more filter)